# Unable to set different app icon for different localizations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, localization

I have followed all the steps in for displaying different app icon for different localization.

Like first i have enabled the localization for Icon.png
Then i add the localization through button Add Localization. I am doing this for italian (it) language.
Then i right clicked the "it" localization and then reveal in finder and there i have replaced the Icon.png with the other Icon.png image for my italian app icon.

Then i have deleted the build folder and then clean all targets and then run the project.

But i am not getting different app icons when i change the iphone language.

Can any body help me in this.

Comment: Did you delete the app from iPhone and re-installed it?

Comment: ohh yes i have...Are there any other step that i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't localize the app icon.